# How to delay a lambda evaluation so I can substitute lambdas

Tags: coq

I have a statement that two lambdas are the same:

```
G : (fun s' : S => x = s') = (fun s' : S => y = s')
```

And I want to use this to prove `x=y`. My thinking is simple, replace that statement with `(fun s' : S => x = s') y`, use `G` to replace one lambda with the other, reduce to `y=y`, profit. My problem is in the first step, I can find no way of setting up a statement containing the application of one lambda that Coq doesn't immediately reduce to `x=y`. I want the unapplied lambda to 'stick around' for a moment so I get a chance to apply `G`.

This seems like it should be easy an just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, `replace (x=y) with (fun s' : S => x = s') y` does not give anything useful since the conclusion is simplified. But this is not the case of `change (x=y) with (fun s' : S => x = s') y` that you can use here to do what you want.

However, the simplest approach is probably `pattern y` which directly transforms the conclusion into the appropriate form.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `pose proof (equal_f G y)` to get `(x = y) = (y = y)`. `equal_f` is from `Coq.Logic.FunctionalExtensionality`.

```
equal_f : forall {A B : Type} {f g : A -> B}, f = g -> forall x : A, f x = g x

equal_f is not universe polymorphic
Arguments equal_f {A B}%type_scope {f g}%function_scope _ _
equal_f is opaque
Expands to: Constant Coq.Logic.FunctionalExtensionality.equal_f
```